# Can gRPC (.net Core Implementation) consume WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, grpc

I have several legacy WCF services that I am proposing be converted to gRPC .Net Core.  The one point I need clarification on and have not been able to find a answer for is, can a .Net Core gRPC app consume a WCF service?

The legacy WCF services I propose converting would still need to talk to existing WCF services that are out of my project scope.
Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WCF client based on DotNet Core enables the application built on DotNet Core to communicate with WCF services.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf
This compatible solution has not implemented Ws* binding, Message security mode yet. Therefore, there are certain services cannot be invocated properly.
the practical scenario depends on the existing WCF service, most of the cases, if we can generate a client proxy by the below tool, the invocation can be completed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.